Is it possible to reuse predictor fixed parameters in a nonlinear mixed effects model fit across mulitple nonlinear response parameters using nlme?
I have data where I want to fit a model given that I know the value at time zero of one stage is equal to the asymptotic value of the previous stage. In particular, I have kinetic growth curves following the SSasymp function in R, such that the predicted nonlinear parameters change each time the process conditions are altered. Sometimes they go up, and sometimes they go down. However, the protocol I am using is consistent.
Is there some trick to accomplishing this constraint within nlme, or do I have to use saemix for something like this?

I realized this is very doable if I make a dedicated model function for my specific application.
